# WCF Client Performance on WM (Compact Framework 3.5)

Tags: performance, wcf, compact-framework

I have a WCF CF Client running on WM 6.5. The proxy classes are generated with NetCFSvcUtil.exe.

When I start the client the connection time to service is about 100 ms, after running an endurance test (300 WS calls) the connection time is about 1500 ms. After restart of my application the connection times are again "normal" about 100 ms.

Any ideas why the performance worsens?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There were memory leaks in CFClientBase.

[Memory Leak in CFClientBase](http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2013/03/31/memory-leak-in-cfclientbaselttgt-service-proxy-for-compact-framework-.net.aspx)

Simply override Equals and GetHashCode in CFContractSerializerInfo.